# MYSQL, using multiple SUMS, not summing multiple columns together

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, sum

so i am trying to get some nice statistics together but am having an issues getting this one to work. It seems like it should be fairly basic but cant for the life of me get this to work and all searched I've come across are people trying to sum columns together (ie a simple sum(a+b+c) as t type thing

my tables looks like:

```
btcfrom | btc to | btc | btctime
usera      userb   5     3204580
usera      userc   2     3450342
userb      userc   1     3428925
userc      usera   2     2358734
```

what i am trying to achieve is a query that returns:

```
btcto| btcgot | timesgot | btcsent | timessent
usera    2          1        7           2
userb    5          1        1           1
userc    3          2        2           1
```

so the code I thought might do this is:

```
SELECT btcto,SUM(btc) AS btcgot, COUNT(btc) AS timesgot 
       (SELECT btcfrom, sum(btc) as btcsent, COUNT(btc) AS timessent 
         FROM tblBots 
         GROUP BY btcfrom) AS s 
 FROM tblBots 
 WHERE btcto=s.btcfrom
 GROUP BY btcto ORDER BY btcgot DESC
```

but just throws me errors. if anyone can at least point me in the right direction for this i'd be very grateful

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query just needs minor fixing:

```
SELECT btcto,SUM(btc) AS btcgot, COUNT(btc) AS timesgot, btcsent, timessent
from tblBots
       join (SELECT btcfrom, sum(btc) as btcsent, COUNT(*) AS timessent 
         FROM tblBots 
         GROUP BY btcfrom) AS s on btcto=s.btcfrom
GROUP BY btcto 
ORDER BY btcto
```

Alternatively, as you are essentially combining two separate queries you could use an UNION:

```
select btcto, sum(btcgot), sum(timesgot), sum(btcsent), sum(timessent)
from (
  select btcto, sum(btc) as 'btcgot', count(*) as 'timesgot', 0 as 'btcsent', 0 as 'timessent'
  from tblBots
  group by btcto
  union
  select btcfrom, 0, 0, sum(btc), count(*)
  from tblBots
  group by btcfrom ) as q
group by btcto;
```

Comment: awesome. this is exactly what I was after. cheers for the help! :D seems I just had things in the wrong order! Im not really used to nested selects

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the results, you need to aggregate your table twice, once on the "to" and once on the "from" to get the summaries you want.

In some dialects of SQL, you can use `full outer join` to comine the two sets.  You can also use `union all` and then re-aggregate the data:

```
select BTCto, sum(TimesGot) as TimesGot, sum(BTCgot) as BTCgot,
       sum(BTCsent) as BTCsent, sum(TimeSent) as TimeSent
from ((select BTCto, count(*) as TimesGot, sum(btc) as BTCgot,
              NULL as BTCsent, NULL as TimeSent
       from tblBots t
       group by BTCto
      ) union all
      (select BTCfrom, NULL as TimesGot, NULL as BTCgot,
              count(*) as BTCsent, sum(btc) as TimeSent
       from tblBots t
       group by BTCfrom
      )
     ) t
gorup by btcTo;
```

Your query doesn't work for several reasons.  But it is trying to give a table alias to a subquery in the `select` clause.  You can only use a table alias on things in the `from` clause.